# listing file link from drive folder link

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-drive-api

Requirement: to create simple web page where user can paste
Google drive folder link And the click button to generate all file links of that folder

What resources above task will require

Does google drive API support external link?

I want do something like this
https://gfycat.com/AccomplishedQuaintBilby

Comment: You can this using google drive API. and what do you mean by external link?

Comment: Means , link which does not belongs to my account, but can be accessible

Comment: `webContentLink` returns the downloadable URL. but the file should be shared with other accounts in order to access it. try to make a file sharable programmatically.

Comment: Welcome. Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested on [ask].